# How to call selector inside selector with parameter in ngrx?

Tags: angular, ngrx

How to call selector inside selector in ngrx?

I have selectors from the adapter:

```
const { selectAll, selectEntities } = productAdapter.getSelectors();
```

And another selectors to get the products and then the product by id I pass in the props.

```
const getProductsEntities = createSlector(getProductState, (state) => selectEntites(state));

const selectProductById = createSelector(getProductsEntities , (entities, props) => {
 return entities[props?.productId]
});
```

Now I want to do another selector and use the `selectProductById` selector.

```
const selectProductViewById = createSelector(
 selectProductById,

 (product) => {
   ...
 } 
)

productView$ = this.store.pipe(select(selectProductViewById, { id: 1 });
```

But this is not working.
Also I get error that the parameter passing is wrong.

So how to call selector **inside** selector with parameter?

Answer (score 3):

First, you don't have to create a new `getProductsEntities` selector by calling `createSelector`. You can use `selectEntities` directly in the `select` call to `store`. Or if you prefer another name you can simply do:

```js
const getProductsEntities = selectEntities;
```

But to answer your question, here is how to implement a selector that takes a parameter as input using factory selectors:

```js
const selectProductById = (productId: string) => createSelector(
  getProductsEntities,
  (entities) => entities[productId]
);

const selectProductViewById = (productId: string) => createSelector(
 selectProductById(productId),
 (product) => {
   ...
 } 
)

productView$ = this.store.select(selectProductViewById(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

In the selector you're using `props?.productId` but when you call the selector you use `{ id: 1 }`.

This should be the same property key.